# How to eliminate Suggested Sites

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I use Windows 7, IE 11. Nothing I do will eliminate Suggested Sites.

1. I read said to: Open Internet Explorer, Go to Tools, go to File, click Suggested Sites, and then click No. There is no File on the Tools Menu that I can see.
2. I read said to: Go to Tools, Internet Options, Advanced tab, under Browsing, uncheck Enable Suggested Sites. It was already unchecked.
3. I have run across is go to Internet Options, Content, Autocomplete Settings, Advanced Tab, under Browsing, uncheck Enable Suggested Sites. It was already unchecked. There is nothing I can do to completely eliminate Suggested Sites. I can delete it directly, but it still returns.

Comment: Stop using Internet Explorer?

Comment: "Stop using IE 11" is not an option, nor is it a real answer. Somewhere I read that it can be done through the Registry, but I can't find the source again.